# WebService not loading dll from PATH environment variable

Tags: c#, web-services, dllimport

I'm hoping someone else has encountered this problem because it's driving me crazy. I have a Web Service that needs to use DLLs in a folder that I have specified in the PATH environment variable (via DLLImport). When I run the service in the development server it works with no problem, if I run the method in a console application it works with no problem. When I publish the service to my IIS and try the method I get:

> Unable to load DLL 'WORKFLOW.DLL': The specified module could not be found.

I even created a WebMethod to return the specified Environment variable for testing:

```
[WebMethod]
public String GetEnv(String variable)
{
    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variable);
}
```

and this returns exactly what I need it to, even when running from IIS, but still its not loading the DLLs. I've been searching all over and can't seem to find anyone with this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security problem.  It doesn't let you just load the DLL like that.
You need to add references in your Web App to those dlls, then those target dlls get copied to your bin folder and you should be okay.  Or those DLLs are not registered in the GAC and there are problems there.

Comment: Also, if its a security issue why would it say "The specified module could not be found" instead of "Access Denied" or something similar?

Comment: The security issue can be that the IIS user that the app is running under cannot access the file space where you have the DLL located.  Maybe.